# Python Selenium + Datepicker Issues

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker, web-scraping

I am trying to get the availability/price for each day in https://www.homeaway.pt/arrendamento-ferias/p418841 by clicking the calendar, checking which days are occupied or not, clicking the `next` button so it can skip to the next month.

I will also want to click on the arrival date and then choose a checkout date so that I can see the price for it.

I am running into issues because I try commands that work in chrome but then they don't seem to work in selenium.

For example:

I do:

```
        self.driver.get(url)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        try:
            elem = wait.until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (
                        By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                        "#startDateInput"
                    )
                )
            )
        except TimeoutException:
            pass
        else:
            elem.send_keys(Keys.NULL)
```

This seems to open the calendar, and I can also list the selectable days with:

```
for x in self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".stab-calendar-day.stab-calendar-day-active.stab-calendar-day-selectable.pull-left"): print(x.get_attribute('data-formatted-date'))
```

But then when I want to skip to the next active month, it keeps showing the same initial month, and that is because this is not working:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.stab-calendar-controls-next').click()
```

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".stab-calendar-controls-next"}

Any ideas on how I can get the availability/price of the house for each set of chosen days?

Comment: I don't have python but I wrote some code in Java and I'm not really finding any issues. I am using a different CSS selector to get the available dates, `"div.stab-calendar-day-selectable:not(.stab-calendar-day-disabled)"`. You will need this to distinguish those dates that are at the end and beginning of the month as placeholders but aren't clickable or you will find that you get repeat dates. When I locate and click the next button with `"a.stab-calendar-controls-next"` it works fine for me. It may be a timing issue, have you tried a wait before clicking next?

Comment: Can you post your Java code so I can have a look and try it that way? I did try waiting with no luck

Comment: You code works fine on Chrome and python, as long as the calendar popup is still being displayed. I cut & pasted with no errors. Check version of selenium? Can you try with another driver (Firefox, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but if you are problem is just that you are not able to click on next button. The solution is simple. please change the selector to click on child element and it will work. I have tested it and it's working on firefox.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".stab-calendar-controls-next > i").click()
```

And following is the whole code which is working. for the first time it will print the the dates of current and next. and then next two months.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.homeaway.pt/arrendamento-ferias/p418841")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
    elem = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (
                By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                "#startDateInput"
            )
        )
    )
except TimeoutException:
    pass
else:
    elem.send_keys(Keys.NULL)

for x in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".stab-calendar-day.stab-calendar-day-active.stab-calendar-day-selectable.pull-left"):
    print(x.get_attribute('data-formatted-date'))
# driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='stab-calendar-controls-next']/i").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".stab-calendar-controls-next > i").click()
for x in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".stab-calendar-day.stab-calendar-day-active.stab-calendar-day-selectable.pull-left"):
    print(x.get_attribute('data-formatted-date'))
```